# mysql, JOIN and exclude matches

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a system which allows me to handle books and the researches people can do when they are looking for books.

The database is mysql, and I have two main tables `BOOKS` and `RESEARCHES`.

```
BOOKS(id *int*, author *string*, title *string*, price *string*, tags *set('sci-fi', 'literature', 'theatre', 'drama', 'romance', 'recent', ...)*, ...) 

RESEARCHES is (researches_id, price_max, author, ...)
```

When I add a book in my database, I want to get the researches matching to this new book.
As people can use many tags in their researches (more than 30), I decided to create another table, and not to use a tags column in `RESEARCHES` which would have been a `SET`, 
because I believe there is no index on a `SET` column, and so my database can not rapidly handle my request.

```
RESEARCHES_TAGS(id, researches_id, tag).
```

If I add a book by P.K Dick, with the tags 'sci-fi', 'drama', I want to get the researches with tag as `NULL` or tag in ('sci-fi', 'drama') and to exclude
researches with other tags.

So I'm doing the following request:

```
SELECT * FROM RESEARCHES
LEFT JOIN RESEARCHES_TAGS ON RESEARCHES.researches_id = RESEARCHES_TAGS.researches_id AND RESEARCHES_TAG.tag IN ('literature', 'theatre', 'romance', ...)
WHERE RESEARCHES_TAGS.tag IS NULL
```

Note that the specified tags array doesn't contain the tags 'sci-fi', 'drama'.

My question is: is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is to **exclude** the rows linked with tags 'literature', 'theatre', 'romance', etc. and keep only rows without criteria, or with matching criteria (sci-fi or drama or both).
The query you propose does the opposite.

I myself usually goes with the `LEFT JOIN j WHERE j.id IS NULL` statement, but it is obviously a counter-intuitive solution.

Maybe redefining the tables structure would allow a simpler and/or faster query? Let's rephrase the problem...

```
Will asks for any products
Jane asks for products with at least A and B
John asks for products with at least C
Yael asks for products with at least A and C
Mark asks for products with at least A
```

You possess a product that meets A and B requirements. Who are you to sell it to ?

The answer being Will, Jane and Mark, how do you put it in tables and query ?

If you only have a few types of requirements, you put a field for each one, and ask for `WHERE C = 0 AND D = 0`, because you do not want to contact people who require something you do not have. But what if you have a growing list of criteria ? You can't just keep adding fields. And using a set field would exclude the possibility to work with an index.

Comment: The way you've rephrased the problem is very nice, and matches my concerns.

I have actually a growing list of criteria, I can't create a column for each one indeed.

So, yes, how to get the researches of Will, Jane and Mark with a more properly way than the "LEFT JOIN j WHERE j.id IS NULL" statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your `JOIN` criteria separate from your `WHERE` criteria. Also, an `INNER JOIN` makes more sense to me, since you won't have a `RESEARCHES_TAGS` row without a corresponding `RESEARCHES` row... right?

```
SELECT * FROM RESEARCHES
INNER JOIN RESEARCHES_TAGS ON RESEARCHES.researches_id = RESEARCHES_TAGS.researches_id 
WHERE RESEARCHES_TAGS.tag IS NULL OR tag IN ('literature', 'theatre', 'romance', ...)
```

Also... you should clarify this query to indicate which table `tag` belongs to.